# How to calculate number of non blank rows based on the value using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a table with numeric values and blank records. I'm trying to calculate a number of rows that are not blank and bigger than 20.

```
+--------+
| VALUES |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      0 |
|     13 |
|     40 |
|        |
|      1 |
|    200 |
|      4 |
|    135 |
|        |
|     35 |
+--------+
```

I've tried different options but constantly get the next error: "Cannot convert value '' of type Text to type Number". I understand that blank cells are treated as text and thus my filter (>20) doesn't work. Converting blanks to "0" is not an option as I need to use the same values later to calculate AVG and Median.

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Table3),
    VALUE(Table3[VALUES]) > 20
    )
```

OR getting "10" as a result:

```
=CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(ALLNOBLANKROW(Table3[VALUES])),
    VALUE(Table3[VALUES]) > 20
    )
```

The final result in the example table should be: 4

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `VALUE` function expects a string. It converts strings like `"123"`into the integer `123`, so let's not use that.

---

The easiest approach is with an iterator function like `COUNTX`.

```
CountNonBlank = COUNTX(Table3, IF(Table3[Values] > 20, 1, BLANK()))
```

Note that we don't need a separate case for `BLANK()` (null) here since `BLANK() > 20` evaluates as `False`.

There are tons of other ways to do this. Another iterator solution would be:

```
CountNonBlank = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table3, Table3[Values] > 20))
```

You can use the same `FILTER` inside of a `CALCULATE`, but that's a bit less elegant.

```
CountNonBlank = CALCULATE(COUNT(Table3[Values]), FILTER(Table3, Table3[Values] > 20))
```

---

**Edit**

I don't recommend the `CALCULATE` version. If you have more columns with more conditions, just add them to your `FILTER`. E.g.

```
CountNonBlank =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(Table3,
        Table3[Values] > 20
            && Table3[Text] = "xyz"
            && Table3[Number] <> 0
            && Table3[Date] <= DATE(2018, 12, 31)
    )
)
```

You can also do OR logic with `||` instead of the `&&` for AND.

Comment: Thank you! Though the last code doesn't work, I get this error: "Calculation error in measure 'Table3'[measure 3]: A function 'FILTER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed." I tried to use the last code as I will have a second column with another criteria and I assume it would be easier to add that parameter within "Calculate" function.

Comment: My bad, I misplaced one bracket.. Though I still get an error: "The function COUNT takes an argument that evaluates to numbers or dates and cannot work with values of type String."

Comment: I don't recommend the last one. Use the middle one and add more conditions.

Comment: I tried the middle one, slightly changed it to `COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table3, VALUE(Table3[Values]) > 20))` but still getting an error: "Cannot convert value '' of type Text to type Number"

Comment: Is `Table3[Values]` a number column or a text column? If it's numerical, then you should not be using `VALUE`, as I explained in the first sentence of my answer. If it's text, then I don't know why you're comparing to a number.

Comment: I have a SQL query where I tried to substitute NULL values with "blanks" so records with numbers were converted to varchar... But apparently, I cannot convert my records back to numeric in excel now and need to find another solution.

Comment: the issue is that I'm not using the query editor but just copy the query results to an excel tab (because a customer needs to see the raw data as well to do some validation). I tried to change the data type using "Manage Data Model" option but it gives me an error. So now I'm thinking if there is a way to change the data type in the SQL query leaving "blanks" instead of NULL (couldn't find how to do that yet). Or keep NULLs but then I think I will have the same "Text/Numeric" issue in PowerPivot..

Comment: You can load tables from a sheet into the query editor and then load that to the data model, but an easier option might be to just create a new calculated column in your data model that does the conversion and then use that column in your measure.

Comment: Thank you Alex! I decided to load data using SQL (in query editor) and then load it into a table so the customer could see the raw data. Looks like it works okay now.